# after deleting the docker images from nexus repository web interface the space is not freed up, remains the same and it is taking up my space

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I am running the nexus repository on docker container Nexus version :3:3.41.1. the space goes on increasing, Need help.

Also the cleanup policy does not work, I think because, I have created the blob storage and repository locally so it asks for health check to cleanup but the health check does not apply as I have created it locally (A Repository Health Check (RHC) cannot be performed on this repository, because it is an unsupported type or out of service.)
[Nexus screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khy2A.png)

I Tried everything and also deleted the nexus container with my volume, which is gone and created this new container which also does not seem to free up space.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run two maintenance tasks in the admin UI to reclaim space:

- Docker - Delete unused manifests and images
- Admin - Compact blob store

See [How to delete docker images](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009696054-How-to-delete-docker-images-from-Nexus-Repository-3)